# Failing to insert into table getting error: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [ktssinseg2]

Tags: oracle

I am facing problems inserting records into my oracle database 12C R2. I have no Oracle Support. All this time I was able to do inserts into my database, but all of a sudden it is now failing. Below is the query and error:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO MV_IN_SMS_TOTAL SELECT * FROM mv_in_sms_total@newdwhlink.com WHERE START_DATE = '20191101';
INSERT INTO MV_IN_SMS_TOTAL SELECT * FROM mv_in_sms_total@newdwhlink.com WHERE START_DATE = '20191101'
                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [ktssinseg2], [60], [7],
[289598865], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Comment: ORA-00600 typically means you need to contact the Oracle support as this usually indicates an Oracle bug.

Comment: Thank you, so that means with the absence of Oracle Support it basically means that my database is dead and nothing can be done about it?

Comment: Is there anything else in the alert log to work with? 
1. Try replacing "select *" - which should never be used in Production code - with the required column names.  
2. Make sure that the database link is working correctly on its own.  
3. Get yourself hooked up with Oracle Support.  To be blunt, running anything important to your organisation on Oracle databases without this safety net is just insane!

Comment: The columns are all simple. i have also tried to used avoid select * and instead used the actual columns but still faced same error. The Alert log doesn't seem to show much:  KQRCMT: Write failed with error=1655 po=00007FF7FD129230 cid=2
diagnostics : cid=2 hash=0xa0b5cca5 flag=0x26

*** 2020-02-26T14:51:30.640719+02:00 (RVASPDB(3))
2020-02-26 14:51:30.637*:ksq.c@12954:ksqdld_hdr_dump(): 
DEADLOCK DETECTED ( ORA-00060 )
See Note 60.1 at My Oracle Support for Troubleshooting ORA-60 Errors

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to insert into a materialized view?  MV_IN_SMS_TOTAL??  can you run the sub statement SELECT * FROM mv_in_sms_total@newdwhlink.com WHERE START_DATE = '20191101';

Comment: Hi. Kevin: 1. MV_IN_SMS_TOTAL is not a materialized view. 2. I am able to run: SELECT * FROM mv_in_sms_total@newdwhlink.com WHERE START_DATE = '20191101'; and get results.

Answer (score 1):

The closest bug match is  `Bug 32711099  ORA-600 [ktssinseg2] - ktssinseg`

But this wasn't reported until 19.8 and fixed in 19.17. Nevertheless, sometimes these near-matches can be helpful. The only information Oracle provides is:

```
Call Stack will likely include:
 
...ktssinseg ktsscrsegfmt ktsscrseg ktssctr_segment1 ktssctr_segment ktrsexecExecuteInExcepHdlr...
 
Rediscovery Information:
If ORA-600 [ktssinseg2] occurs during segment creation for insert query,
then you are hitting this bug.
```

The mention of "segment creation" is helpful. Does your table already have a segment created (see the `SEGMENT_CREATED` column in `DBA_TABLES`). If not, try recreating the target table with the "`SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE`" clause so that the insert doesn't have to create the segment. That might bypass the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to copy the table into a new object:

```
CREATE TABLE newtab AS SELECT * FROM MV_IN_SMS_TOTAL
```

Try to do your inserts into the new table. If that solves the problem and the problem is isolated to that specific object (table), and you use that as a workaround.

```
RENAME TABLE MV_IN_SMS_TOTAL TO MV_IN_SMS_TOTAL_OLD;
CREATE TABLE MV_IN_SMS_TOTAL AS SELECT * FROM MV_IN_SMS_TOTAL_OLD;
```

Note that all auxiliary objects must be created. Indexes, constraints, triggers, you name it - and privileges.

Regards,

Daniel